# Awaiting multiple asynchronous object[key] = value assignments inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, object, asynchronous, foreach, async-await

I trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries. Each item in the dictionary is assigned asynchronously. I would like to wait until all items are assigned before printing the result to the console.

## Program

```
const dict = {};

async function placeholder (letter, number) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    return 'test';
}

async function secondMethod (letter, number) {
    try {
        dict[letter][number] = await placeholder (letter, number);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

async function firstMethod (letter) {
    dict[letter] = {};
    const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
    await numbers.forEach (number => secondMethod (letter, number));
}

async function main () {
    const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    await letters.forEach (letter => firstMethod (letter));
    console.log (dict)
};

main ();
```

## Result

```
{ a: {}, b: {}, c: {}, d: {} }
```

## Desired Result

```
{
  a: { '1': 'test', '2': 'test', '3': 'test', '4': 'test' },
  b: { '1': 'test', '2': 'test', '3': 'test', '4': 'test' },
  c: { '1': 'test', '2': 'test', '3': 'test', '4': 'test' },
  d: { '1': 'test', '2': 'test', '3': 'test', '4': 'test' }
}
```

Comment: `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` return promises which you aren't awaiting - `.forEach` always returns `undefined`, so no point awaiting that, it's not a Promise - as an aside, you almost never want to use async/await inside a `.forEach` (you're not, but you may think that's the fix for your failure, it isn't) - you probably wanted something like `await Promise.all(numbers.map(number => secondMethod (letter, number)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Array.forEach` is a synchronous function, you cannot call `await` on it. You'll need to restructure your code flow to use proper async loops to reach the desired result.

### Using the await in every single call:

```js
const dict = {};

async function placeholder(letter, number) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));
    return 'test';
}

async function secondMethod(letter, number) {
    try {
        dict[letter][number] = await placeholder (letter, number);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

async function firstMethod(letter) {
    dict[letter] = {};
    const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
    for (const number of numbers) {
        await secondMethod (letter, number);
    }
}

async function main() {
    const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    for (const letter of letters) {
        await firstMethod(letter);
    }
    console.log(dict)

    // pretty html result
    let resultContainer = document.getElementById("result")
    resultContainer.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dict, null, 2)

};

main();
```

```html
<h2> Result: </h2>
<pre id="result">Waiting results...</pre>
```

### Using promise.all to have all the promises execute in "parallel"

```js
const dict = {};

async function placeholder(letter, number) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));
    return 'test';
}

async function secondMethod(letter, number) {
    try {
        dict[letter][number] = await placeholder (letter, number);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

async function firstMethod(letter) {
    dict[letter] = {};
    const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
    const promises = [];
    for (const number of numbers) {
        promises.push(secondMethod (letter, number));
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
}

async function main() {
    const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    const promises = [];
    
    for (const letter of letters) {
        promises.push(firstMethod(letter));
    }

    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(dict);

    // pretty html result
    let resultContainer = document.getElementById("result")
    resultContainer.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dict, null, 2)

};

main();
```

```html
<h2> Result: </h2>
<pre id="result">Waiting results...</pre>
```

Comment: If you're awaiting each individual method call, then isn't this synchronous essentially?

Comment: yeah, it behaves like it is, but in practice, any async function is basically nested promises everytime there's an `await`

Comment: If you're trying to have all the methods being executed in parallel, you can use a `Promise.all` call to have them execute in parallel and then proceed when every single one returns. I'll amend my answer with this case aswell

Answer (score -1):

I *think* this should solve it for you.

```js
async function firstMethod (letter) {
    dict[letter] = {};
    const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
    await numbers.forEach(async function (number) {
        return await secondMethod(letter, number);
    });
}

async function main () {
    const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    await letters.forEach(async function (letter) {
        return await firstMethod(letter);
    });
    console.log (dict);
}
```